# Getting both Id's from inner join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I am working on a website in the php Codeigniter framework, and am having problems with joining tables together.

The two tables are meals and restaurants, simply with the versions

```
meals: id, restaurant_id, price, etc.

restaurants: id, name, location, etc.
```

To make the query I use the following code:

```
$this->db->join('restaurants', 'restaurants.id = meals.restaurant_id');
$query = $this->db->get('meals');
```

which returns the same result as running this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM meals INNER JOIN restaurants ON restaurants.id = meals.restaurant_id');
```

The problem is that when I access the result in the form of a php array or and object (as supplied by codeigniter DB class), there is only one id returned, the restaurant id, and I need the meal id. How can I get it to spit out the meal id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not experienced with your current tools (php/codeigniter/etc.), and I'm assuming the problem comes about because both tables have the same name for the "id" column?  (That's not normally a problem... but maybe the tools don't handle it right?)  As for the SQL query, one way to differentiate columns with the same name is to use aliases in the select statement.  Here is an example:

```
select
    m.id as meal_id,
    m.price as meal_price,
    r.id as restaurant_id,
    r.name as restaurant_name,
    r.location as restaurant_location
from meals as m
inner join restaurants as r on r.id = m.restaurant_id
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Turns out someone had exactly the same problem with the same solution: [link](http://chrissilich.com/blog/codeigniter-active-record-aliasing-column-names-to-prevent-overwriting-especially-columns-named-id/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT t1.id as mid,t2.id as rid
  FROM table_meals as t1
  inner JOIN table_restaurant as t2 ON t2.id = t1.`restaurant_id`
```